# Difference between PreConfigureServices and ConfigureServices

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, abp

I'm using the ABP framework with multiple modules and need to run join queries on a single DbContext. When I attempted to replace the DbContext of all modules with a single one from the main app in ConfigureServices, it didn't work and showed the following error.

> [ERR] Cannot use multiple context instances within a single query execution. Ensure the query uses a single context instance.
> However, when I added the code in PreConfigureServices, it worked. Why does configuring the DbContext in PreConfigureServices make a difference compared to ConfigureServices in the ABP framework?

```
    context.Services.AddAbpDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultRepositories(includeAllEntities: true);

    });
```

I want to know the actual reason, why didn't it work on ConfigureServices.

Comment: Likely because ABP sets things up a particular way by default and expects alterations to the DbContext configuration to be done prior to ConfigureServices otherwise it uses its own default configuration. PreConfigureServices is essentially a setup that ConfigureServices will consume. If you were overriding ConfigureServices, did you add `base.ConfigureServices(...);` at the end of your method? The source for ABP is available at https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev so with a little digging you can probably find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the differences between `ConfigureServices` and `PreConfigureServices` methods in [this documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Development-Basics#configuring-dependency-injection-other-modules), but here are some important differences:

The `ConfigureServices` method is where you need to add your services into the DI container, configure options, and perform other service-related configurations.

On the other hand, the `PreConfigureServices` method is used to make your registrations just before the `ConfigureServices` method is run. This means it allows you to perform any necessary configuration or setup before the standard service configuration process begins. (Typically, you might use this method to configure certain services or settings that need to be in place before the rest of the application services are configured.)